# "incomplete type is not allowed" for interrupt service routine for PIC

Tags: c, pic

When I try to compile the code for a PIC program using PICMicro C compiler, I got the error "incomplete type is not allowed" for the interrupt service routine part of the code:

```
char chB = 0;
int clicks = 0;
void interrupt ISR(void) //incomplete type is not allowed
{
    if(RBIF == 1)
    {
        clicks++;
        chB = PORTB;
        RBIF = 0;
    }
}
```

After checking multiple sources, I still do not see how the service routine is incorrectly written..

Edit:
Thanks for all your help, I have found the solution:

```
char chB = 0;
int clicks = 0;
#pragma vector = 0x04
__interrupt void isr(void)
{
    if(RBIF == 1)
    {
        clicks++;
        chB = PORTB;
        RBIF = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using GCC, try with `void __attribute__ ((interrupt)) ISR(void)`

Comment: I suspect the `ISR` identifier is a macro that requires an ISR name...

Comment: @H2CO3 the ISR identifier is a random function name. I changed to other names and it still is not working..

Comment: @Jigsore Sorry, I forgot to mention I am using the PICMicro C compiler so I just edited my post. I tried it but now the compiler states "expected a type specifier", "unnamed prototyped parameters not allowed when body is present", "expected a "{"".

Answer (score 1):

"interrupt ISR" is not a valid name, because it has a space in it. `void interrupt_isr(void)` should be fine.

Comment: The interrupt keyword is required to identify the function as an interrupt service routine, otherwise it will be regarded as a normal function and the interrupt may not function as required.

Answer (score 0):

For PIC16xxx family MCUs use this form:

```
void interrupt () {

  } // end interrupt
```